# How to use not mapped entity fields in query builder

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine

I have a question.
I have an entity which has an not mapped field type in it.
How can i use this field in query builder for building queries?
The problem is since not mapped fields are not available in mysql tables, we cannot use them in SQL queries directly.
is there any way to use them in Doctrine Query builder?
thanks ;)

Answer (score 2):

You've got several options :

- either you **map your fields**, ( why not ? that's what doctrine is for... :-) )
- **or** you **use [NativeQuery](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html).** The [docs for this are here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html).
- **or** use the **doctrine DBAL** and pass on your query using prepare/execute/fetchAll ([This is documented here](http://doctrine-dbal.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html#using-prepared-statements)). Something like :

```php
 $sql = "   SELECT ... "; // Your query here
 $connection = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
 $qry = $connection->prepare($sql);
 $qry->execute();
 $results = $qry->fetchAll();

 // Then you can just iterate through $results...
```

Comment: thanks for your solution , i know that i can map my fields to my database but i don't want to do this because of preventing data redundancy , and also i want to know does Doctrine has a solution that for example sort fetched entities by value of an unmapped field?

Comment: @Mohammad , I've edited my answer. Check the syntax using doctrine's Database Abstraction Layer.